# Uninstall a manually installed program

Tags: software-installation, uninstall

I have installed a program (taskwarrior.org) manually --- cmake, make, make install, etc.

How do I completely uninstall a program installed this way?

There was no 'uninstall' script in the downloaded zip file.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at `makefile`. There is `install` section with the place of installed files. Simply remove them.